# SPARQL query using multiple datasources

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, linked-data

I have my default graph and I need to extend the data using DBpedia.

I have mapped all instances from my data with their respective URIs from DBpedia, using `owl:sameAs` property.

This query returns all the `owl:sameAs` data: 
(My endpoint: http://dydra.com/brunopenteado/br_municipalities/@query)

```
select * 
  where 
    { 
      ?mun owl:sameAs ?db .
    } 
  limit 10
```

Now I want to query the `rdfs:label` from DBpedia using my data.

How can I build a query that reads my data and extends to DBpedia properties as well?

I tried a query like this, but no results are returned.

```
select * 
  from <http://dydra.com/brunopenteado/br_municipalities/sparql>
  from <http://pt.dbpedia.org/sparql>
where 
  { 
    ?mun owl:sameAs ?dbp .
    ?dbp rdfs:label ?name
  } 
limit 10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FROM` doesn't work, because it's used to identify graphs within your current data source. You can use the `SERVICE` keyword to access multiple SPARQL endpoints from a single query.

```
select * 
where 
{ 
   SERVICE <http://dydra.com/brunopenteado/br_municipalities/sparql>
   {
      ?mun owl:sameAs ?dbp .
      ?dbp rdfs:label ?name
   }

   SERVICE <http://pt.dbpedia.org/sparql>
   {
      ?mun owl:sameAs ?dbp .
      ?dbp rdfs:label ?name
   }
}
```

You may want to add `OPTIONAL` to your service queries. For more information you can read [the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/).

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, for the answer and for the reference! 
Just a minor point: as I was running the query on Dryad, I had to do the following adaptation:

`select * 
where 
{ 
      ?mun owl:sameAs ?dbp .

   SERVICE <http://pt.dbpedia.org/sparql>
   {
      ?dbp rdfs:label ?name
   }
}`